# Meanjs: Which is better? Querying the node server for individual resource or storing all the resources in Angular scope and then accessing the one

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am a little lost here between two approaches. Lets say my app is about displaying latest movies.

There is a movies page where all the movies are displayed with some details but not all.
Let's say the user then clicks on a specific movie, which should take the user to the movie detail page.

Approach # 1 - Should I query the server with the id and get the details to display?

Approach # 2 - I have all the movies stored in mongo db. When I load my app.js with angular initially, I can query all the movies in the db and store them in a controller. So when the user clicks on a specific movie on the movies page, I can just access the movie from the controller using Angular scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to have dozens of movies you can send all data to frontend. But probably your application will grow and then you will have in database thousands of movies. Then Pushing all data to frontend is bad idea.

In summary you can push to frontend all data which is known and sparse.
But data which will grow should be taken from server partially (what user need he will get)

Comment: That is what I was thinking. I the beginning front end code would be faster because of less data but overtime it could be problem if I were to query a lot of movies. Better to configure a route /api/movies/:id on the server. Thanks a lot